# Making debug and release configs for c++ in VS Code

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this question. I'm holding off using an IDE until I can confidently use g++, makefiles, and JSON configs. My issue is that in VS Code, setting up SDL2, I'm not sure how to make a release config (by that I mean code cleaning). Here's what I have in my tasks.json file for debugging.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "SDL2 Debug",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "src\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "bin\\debug\\main.exe",
                "-IC:/SDL2/include",
                "-LC:/SDL2/lib",
                "-lmingw32",
                "-lSDL2main",
                "-lSDL2",
                "-mwindows"            
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
       
    ],
}
```

A lot of this I just copied off the internet. Which is fine because it works, but not fine because I don't understand JSON or how VS Code uses it. And I can't find any references to explain what all this fancy stuff means. And the main problem is that this just creates a debug build, I'm not even sure if the arguments are correct or if it's messy. I want to create a release config alongside this to clean the code once the project is finished. All I'm looking for is a push in the right direction. Not expecting an outright solution to my problem (although that would be great), I just want to understand what I'm supposed to do here. Any references to read would be awesome, I don't know where to look at this point in time.

Comment: JSON is just a metaformat, similar to XML, YAML, CSV. Concerning the VS.code configuration, there are tooltips and hints built into the editor for that configuration file.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I've seen the tooltips, and where some are helpful for understanding, others just say things like "type of configuration". I don't know what types I'm allowed to use, and like I said I tried looking for it but it seems I'm alone in not understanding this.

Comment: Oh, it also has autocompletion: When you delete the `shell` from `"type": "shell"`, place the cursor betwen the double quotes and hit Control-space, it should pop up a list of available options.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I see, that definitely helps a bit, thanks very much.